# Providing restrictive access to web application

Tags: web-applications, hosting

I want to provide restrictive access to web application where normal user will see 'Coming Soon' page but developers can access the application and test their code.
Does it wary to different application server?

Comment: The basic process is going to be the same for the different server-side technologies.  Sounds like you simply want a login for your site, and then check the type of user for access.  Are you currently using anything?

Comment: No. It's not about the login. Let's say when common user visits www.test.com, he will see 'Coming soon' page. But if a developer visits the page he will see the web application page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but developers can access the application and test their code

The simplest I can think of is to do an IP based filtering assuming that the developers work and try to access the server from the same LAN (not going via some public router).
You could have some kind of filter that according to IP could redirect either to the `Coming Soon` page or the web application